# WindowsAzure: Develop on deployed PHP Files

Tags: php, windows, azure, local

I work a lot with the WindowsAzure4E(clipse) IDE. And it's always pain to wait for the local test deployment)

Isn't there a way to develop on the deployed PHP files which must be stored somewhere to inetput or something else?

thx for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that after the deployment the project files are copied to the folder **ServiceDefinition.csx**.

When you now edit the source code in this place, you can see the changes directly, without another deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! In fact, I just got this working myself yesterday.

After installing PHP 5.3 with CGI support for IIS (making the necessary php.ini modifications of course), I simply created a new site in IIS that mapped to a role in the workspace for my Eclipse project.

Keep in mind that there's one hiccup to this and that is that the php_azure.dll file, used to access the service configuration and mount azure drives, was built to run in the azure fabric (either development or hosted). In my case, I don't NEED these features so I removed referrences to things like getconfig and *poof* the project loads in IIS just fine. I only need to make sure I start Azure Storage prior to launching the application.

I've been told that some folks are able to update their systems path environment variable with the location of the azure diagnostics dll (diagnostics.dll) and have it work without this modification. But this route didn't work for me. :(

I'll actually be blogging on this more this weekend as it took me a week of evenings to get things sorted out.